# how to make all nodes ping & reply in OMNet++ simulator scanerio is given below

Tags: omnet++

can any one help me in code of simple ping app
i am trying to ping from 4 nodes but only 2 can communicate in my case

omnet ini code is here

```
# ping app (host[0] pinged by others)
*.host[0].numPingApps = 0
*.host[*].numPingApps = 4
*.host[1].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[0]"
*.host[2].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[0]"
*.host[3].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[0]"
*.host[4].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[0]"

*.host[1].pingApp[*].startTime = 3s
*.host[1].pingApp[*].sendInterval = 1s
*.host[1].pingApp[*].srcAddr = "host[1]"
#*.host[1].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[2]"

*.host[2].pingApp[*].startTime = 2s
*.host[2].pingApp[*].sendInterval = 1s
*.host[2].pingApp[*].srcAddr = "host[2]"
#*.host[2].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[1]"

*.host[3].pingApp[*].startTime = 1s
*.host[3].pingApp[*].sendInterval = 1s
*.host[3].pingApp[*].srcAddr = "host[3]"
#*.host[3].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[4]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosts 1, 2, 3, and 4 should have only one `pingApp`. Moreover, `srcAddr` may be omitted, because this field will be automatically set by network layer. So minimal `omnetpp.ini` should look like:

```
*.host[0].numPingApps = 0
*.host[0].pingApp[0].destAddr = ""

*.host[*].numPingApps = 1
*.host[*].pingApp[0].destAddr = "host[0]"
```